# batch y/n popup possible?

Tags: javascript, batch-file, hta

I stumbled upon a bit of code  that creates a popup, and you can edit the text from it, add multiple lines...

```
mshta javascript:alert("Line 1\n Line 2");close();
```

Go ahead and fire up command prompt and enter in that line.  I guess that the \n means next line, as you can add/delete those all you want.

My question is, is there a way to use that same popup method, but rather than have a single button that says "OK", use two buttons, that when you click one, you "goto a", and when click the other, you "goto b".

I also can't figure out how to modify that other popup that I posted above, to say change it from "HTML APPLICATION" to some other title, and rename the "OK" button to something else.  Either way, that is beside the point, and just curiosity kicking in.

EDIT:  In my last comment, about closing the script, I figured out that I can just throw

```
;close();
```

at the end of the parentheses.  But how can I set the true/false as a variable in the batch script?

**EDIT:  I have decided that autoit is a much better language for this kinda thing.  Voting to have closed.**

Comment: Your code is basically a bookmarklet. If you can write JavaScript code that composes the appropriate HTML to display a custom dialogue and make it fit into a single line, you might get what you want, but it's going to be a convoluted way to do it. And there's no way to change the title of JavaScript alerts.

Comment: It has nothing whatsoever to do with a batch file, its an HTA (html application): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/scriptcenter/dd742317.aspx

Comment: You could use `confirm()` instead of `alert()`. It returns `true` if user clicks `OK` and `false` if user clicks `Cancel` or closes the window with `X`. Though I guess these values need to be handled within commandline arguments too?

Comment: Maybe you have to change the [scripting technic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)...

Comment: @teemu I realize that now.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, first let me explain what is going on in your example. When you type in:

```
mshta javascript:alert("Line 1\n Line 2");close();
```

what you're actually doing is telling your computer:

> Run the program called mshta.exe, and pass the following *javascript* to it as an argument

You can do this with any program, for example, try opening notepad with a new file called "banana.txt" by typing:

```
notepad banana
```

Note that both cases have virtually nothing to do with batch. In your example, mshta.exe just runs some javascript to open an alert window, just as in my example notepad.exe deals with the creation of the .txt file.

---

Ok, so now that we've got that out of the way, onto your actual question: Is there a way to write a script in batch that will open a popup confirmation window?

The simple answer to your question is no. Batch is very good<sup>[citation needed]</sup> at moving around directories, opening files/programs, and...that's about it. If you need to do *anything* that isn't in that list, you should really be using a different scripting language.

However, while I cannot emphasize enough how much that is the correct answer to your question, I recognize that it's not a very satisfying one, so I will say that if you absolutely *have* to have a solution in batch, I would do something like the following:

```
@echo off

echo code=Msgbox("I'm A Message Box!", vbYesNo, "I'm The Title!") > "%temp%\popupBox.vbs"
echo WScript.Quit code >> "%temp%\popupBox.vbs"
cscript /nologo "%temp%\popupBox.vbs"

if %errorlevel%==6 call :ok_tag
if %errorlevel%==7 call :cancel_tag
echo Done!
exit /b 1

:ok_tag
echo You pressed Yes!
exit /b

:cancel_tag
echo You pressed No!
exit /b
```

This code essentially circumvents your problem by creating and running a temporary vbscript file (another scripting language) whose job is to display a confirmation window for you, and then using the exit code from *that* script to determine which button was clicked.

Notice again how much longer and more complicated this is than simply writing the program in pure vbscript to begin with, but if you must have a .bat file, then a .bat file you shall have.

Comment: In my opinion, `cscript.exe` is the far better solution. Using it with `popupBox.vbs` is the way to go. One small suggestion, the `popupBox.vbs` is shipped with the batch file instead of being created by the batch file. I know it's no longer a single file solution, but, it'll be far more easier to read and maintained the two files than to force a single batch file solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off

    for /f "usebackq" %%f in (
        `mshta "javascript:new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write(new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell').PopUp('Select one',0,'Title',36));close();"`
    ) do (
        if "%%f"=="6" (
            echo YES
        ) else if "%%f"=="7" (
            echo NO
        ) else (
            echo ????
        )
    )
```

Comment: This code makes me cringe even more than mine does :P